# Firebase Hosting custom domain suddenly stopped working while trying to add www redirect

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I had completed setup firebase hosting custom domain after verifying TXT records and A records with IP addresses. and today I tried to add another domain to redirect [www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com) to mysite.com. in the process I deleted previous A records and re-added new records and firebase hosting stopped working soon after. I'm very new to firebase and I have no idea what happened. My domain is purchased from namecheap.com. I also re-added A records hoping it will fix the issue but it didn't.

[image]
it says mysite.com is connected but when I try to access it I get following error.
[image]

Comment: This is typically something you should contact Firebase support about, but the error page you're getting is not a Firebase error page which indicates that the DNS is likely set up incorrectly. Without the details of your actual domain there's not much more help to give.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response sir. I'm sorry I'm not allowed share the domain name at the moment. Is there a way to re-verify domain ownership without contacting firebase support sir?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It started working again automatically a few minutes after resetting A records. But firebase support told me that there should only be A records with IP address in DNS configurations.